# Setting today's date to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I have a NSDate property as below and I wish to set it with today's date.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSDate *todayDate;
```

I tried the following but I am getting an error:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
self.todayDate = [date isToday];
```

I guess, isToday just checks whether the date is today's date and doesn't set the date.

I am getting following 2 errors:

```
Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'NSDate *' is disallowed with ARC
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSDate *' from 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char');
```

How do I set NSDate to today's date in Objective C?

Comment: `NSDate* date = [NSDate date];`

Comment: Though note that your original `NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];` works as well.

Comment: In the context of his code, this would still cause an error i think?

Comment: It (the `alloc/init` version) wouldn't fix the unnecessary `isToday` call, nor would it fix the probable storage leak, but it would run without error and produce the correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-date) has you covered:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
```

This is a common pattern in Apple's frameworks: semantic "factory" class methods. This call replaces your calls to alloc and init, and is a preferred way to work with common objects. It's also a nice pattern to emulate in your own classes :-)

On of the core concepts which should shed light on the "why" is that of immutability. Many objects (NSString, NSNumber, etc) are considered (at least in practice) to be immutable. This means they get their value exactly once: during init. This leads the the "other" answer also being an instantiation-time technique: [a custom initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188--initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow_).

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0];
```

Comment: Well, if you want to do that (the second version), why not go all the way:  `NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];`

Comment: Yup, the real purpose of the expanded answer is to encourage exploration of what is available :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will set your property to todays date. The error is because, as you suspect, you are assigning a boolean to a pointer.

```
self.todayDate = [NSDate date];
```